# windows mobile 5 device freezes on reading from socket

Tags: sockets, windows-mobile, interrupt-handling

I have simple windows mobile 5 application which freezes when device reads the data from network. root cause is network is dropping the packets repeatedly and application is blocking on read call.

i want to exit this application either from within application or at OS level through an interrupt (keypress combination). may i know if there is any simple approach to incorporate this mechanism.

Comment: Sal, show the little bit of code you are using to connect to the socket and we (josef or myself) can show you how to do this using a thread so that it does not block your main application and so you can cancel your asynchronous network call.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately you did not post your socket code. As long as you are not using Async calls, socket access will block. To keep your main thread running, you have to place your socket calls into a separate thread.

I can supply some background here: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/06/01/mobile-development-easy-to-use-background-thread-with-gui-update/ where a simple ping is done in background. The call to IcmpSendEcho will block, but as it is done in a separate thread, the gui is still usable and will get an event fired, when the 'ping' returns.

~josef

Comment: Thanks Josef for information. I understand that reading thread will block trying to read from socket. thats acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Josef for information. I understand that reading thread will block trying to read from socket. thats acceptable. now the requirement is to kill the application which is blocked on read with some kind of hardware interrupt or software interrupt. apprecaite if some one could hint on creating and handling interrupt on windows mobile device which is struck in some activity like reading from file or socket